# Filed to build Astrid app from source

Tags: android, resources, android-theme

I trying to build Astrid app from source, but I have several errors after export code to Eclipse:

```
2012-02-04 17:25:24 - GreenDroid] R.java was modified manually! Reverting to generated version
2012-02-04 17:25:25 - astridApi] R.java was modified manually! Reverting to generated version
2012-02-04 17:25:25 - facebook] R.java was modified manually! Reverting to generated version
2012-02-04 17:25:27 - astrid]     (skipping hidden file /home/zemik/workspace/astrid/api/res/.gitignore')
2012-02-04 17:25:27 - astrid] /home/zemik/workspace/astrid/greendroid/GreenDroid/res/values-v5/gd_themes.xml:22: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name @android:style/Theme.Wallpaper.
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Error logs says that "R.java was modified manually" . if you go to R.Java, it already stats the you must not Edit R.java file, It is auto generated file by Android System. R.java file contains all the component's ids specified in xml file. So It is adviced to never Edit it. Better you now start with a fresh Project.

Answer (score 1):

On the menu go to Project -> clean and select the project you're working on, and make sure you check the Start a build immediately. If not you can delete `R.java` and clean and build the project. This should solve your problem.

Comment: After clean all my projects I have one error about theme.wallpaper.

Comment: Then it is saying Theme.Wallpaper is not valid. Go to http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html and see if you can use a different parameter.